# Сборка typescript с помощью gulp-webpack

Tags: javascript, gulp, typescript, webpack

Есть тестовый проект, его структура:

[image: project structure]

Так выглядят файлы *.ts:

```
import {ActionsCollection} from "./actionsCollection";
class Greeter extends ActionsCollection{

}
var greeter = new Greeter();
alert(greeter.greet("Hello, world!"));
```

и

```
export class ActionsCollection{
    public say (){

    }
    public greet(greeting :string) {
        return "<h1>"+greeting+"</h1>";
    }
}
```

Так выглядит gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('ts/**/*.ts').pipe(webpack({
        watch: true,
        output: {
            filename: 'main.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
            ]
        }
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('js/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function() {
    gulp.watch('ts/**/*.ts', ['default']);
});
```

Все это вроде бы как и компилится в единый файл `main.js`, но работает это как-то странно. Например когда я изменяю файл `actionsCollection.ts`, не всегда срабатывает компиляция. И еще, если я создам новый файл `new.ts` и не буду его импортировать внутри `greeter.ts` или `actionsCollection.ts`, то он и не попадет в общий скомпилированный файл `main.js`. Это ужасно, т.к. такие файлы будут, и их методы могут быть вызваны неявно.

Я так понимаю что я неправильно настроил конфиг, не могли бы вы меня поправить, таким образом, чтобы при изменении любого `*.ts` файла происходила компиляция в `main.js`, и так чтобы при создании нового `*.ts` при условии что его не импортнули внутри какого-либо другого файла `*.ts`, он все равно компилировался в `main.js`

Comment: "если я создам новый файл `new.ts` и не буду его импортировать", то там будет мёртвый код, который компилировать нет смысла. А ещё я не вижу указания главного файла и вижу попытку сборки всего и вся вместо дерева модулей с импортами. ._.

Comment: @D-side, можете в ответе поправить?

Comment: Если б я мог ответить на вопрос, я б ответил .-.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка вида `'ts/**/*.ts'` интерпретируется как `'ts/folder/file.ts`, а у вас файлы лежат сразу в 'ts/'.

Что касается новых файлов - нужно перезапустить watch, чтобы он их проиндексировал.